# minted package: Undefined control sequence

Tags: minted

I just installed the minted package to type prettier code in my university reports, I'm trying it out but I keep getting the same messages when compiling:

This is the source:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{c}
  int i,j,k,n;
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

I compile it with:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape source.tex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./source.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, spanish, galician, catalan, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./minted.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz)) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty) (./ifplatform.sty))
! Undefined control sequence.
\minted.sty-h@@k ...elax  \ifnum \pdf@shellescape 
                                                  =1\relax \else \PackageErr...
l.3 

? ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   =
l.3 

? 
! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 

? /usr/bin/pygmentize
(./source.aux) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (./source.pyg) (./source.out.pyg) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/p
dftex.map}] (./source.aux) )</usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
ts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10
.pfb>
Output written on source.pdf (1 page, 18733 bytes).
Transcript written on source.log.
```

The output looks as expected but why does all of these messages appear?

Comment: Works fine for me... Looks like something is wrong with either catcodes for `=` or perhgaps the `ifthen` package... Have a look in your source.log file for any extra info.

Comment: Beware that you are using an outdated TeXLive (from your log: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)`). I recommend to install the newest version (see [How to install vanilla TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)).

Comment: When I posted the question I was starting to install the 2012 version just in case that was the problem :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Command `\pdf@shellescape` is defined in package `pdftexcmds` (part of bundle `oberdiek`),
if the TeX compiler supports the status query of the `write18/shell escape` feature.

Therefore just add `\usepackage{pdftexcmds}` before `\usepackage{minted}`.

Comment: The package author of `minted` is notified and he wants to make a new revision of the Google Code version soon.